# How to embed MVC5 project into another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, pluggable

I've developed an MVC5 project to be inserted as a plugin into another MVC5 project . the target is to call one partial view from my project in the new project.
I've tried to make my project published and built a test mvc5 project , how to embed the first project to be used in the new project ?

Note, Both projects are in windows and will be published on iis8

Comment: Use the application as an area. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396